# How to sync after a 'snapper delete'

Tags: btrfs, synchronization, snapshot, snapper

I have started a `snapper delete` command, only to find out five minutes later that it is running in the background and seems to take a longer time. Is there a command can I use to get notified when the deletions are done?
(I would have expected a `snapper sync`.)

(Of course, next time I will simply use the provided `--sync` option.)

Edit:
I have now tried `btrfs filesystem sync /`, but after this command finishes, I still see progress in consecutive `df /` commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding [snapper issue "Provide a 'snapper sync' command to sync a running deletion"](https://github.com/openSUSE/snapper/issues/468) was categorized as "enhancement" by a snapper developer.

This means that this functionality is not available yet.